# couchdb conflict identical document

Tags: couchdb, conflict

In version 1.2 of CouchDB.
Does anyone know that if two identical documents with identical ids are inserted into two databases and then a replication is done from one to the other will there be a conflict?

Comment: Yes. Is there more to your question? Have you tried this yourself yet?

Answer (score 0):

I didn't yet try it.  But I guess if this happens one would want to resolve the confict automatically since the documents are the same it doesn't matter which one is the latest.

Answer (score 0):

In CouchDB versions >= 0.10 there will not be a conflict.

This is because conflicts are detected by spotting differing revisions that do not appear in the document's history. Revision numbers are deterministic on document data (including id) and history, so will be exactly the same for any two identical new documents, and CouchDB will not even know there's an issue.

Older versions (versions up to 0.9) used random revision numbers, which would cause conflicts in this case.

See http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/conflicts.html#deterministic for more information. There's also more information on the finer details of revision number generation at the start of http://csm.tumblr.com/post/18963100318/how-couchdb-revision-number-generation-works.